# Object of array.length is not defined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

when i send the id to api. i got the response in object and consist of itemprice array. but object.itemprice.length is undefined. and object of itemprice undefined

```
//Controller:

ZustShopController.controller("ProductController",function($rootScope,$scope,DecreaseQuantitytService){
$scope.itemslist=DecreaseQuantitytService.DecreseQuantiyItem(item)
})

//Service:

ZustShopService.service("DecreaseQuantitytService",function(DecreaseQuantitytFactory){
    this.DecreseQuantiyItem=function(item){
   return DecreaseQuantitytFactory.DecreseAllQuantiyItem(item)
}
});

//Factory:

 ZustShopFactory.factory("DecreaseQuantitytFactory",function($resource,RES_URL){

var iteminfo;
var itemresource=$resource(RES_URL+"product/:id/:itemcode",{"itemcode":"@itemcode"},{update:{method:"PUT"}})

return{
 DecreseAllQuantiyItem:function(item){
     iteminfo=itemresource.get({"itemcode": item.itemcode,"id":item.prevsubid});
        return iteminfo;
 }

})
```

Json Response

```
Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
__v:3
_id:"573f087078e73e28186a2fb7"
createdAt:"2016-05-20T12:52:00.897Z"
defaultmainprice:180
defaultofferprice:160
isDeleted:false
itemcode:"1000"
itemdescription:"Sun flower 1lit"
itemname:"Sun flower 1lit"
itemprice:Array[2]
modifiedAt:"2016-05-20T12:52:00.898Z"
status:false
subcatid:"5736aea0d3f55f3c155999a8"
unit:"1 lit"
```

`$scope.itemslist.itemprice.length` is undefined

please help me how to do this

Comment: can you please share the code, where you are trying to use `$scope.itemslist.itemprice.length` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your request is not resolved at the moment when you're checking it. You need to use Promise callback to assign loaded data to a scope variable.

```
ZustShopController.controller("ProductController",function($rootScope,$scope,DecreaseQuantitytService){
  DecreaseQuantitytService.DecreseQuantiyItem(item).then(function(data){
    $scope.itemslist = data;
  }
})
```

More on the Promises in [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in angular and [here](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/).

Comment: But i am $resource.

Comment: and so? AJAX call being async, whatever it's wrapped into needs a callback wrapper on some level service or controller - which I don't see in your code example